# How to install TBB on Ubuntu?

Tags: tbb

I downloaded tbb40_233oss_lin.tgz file from http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/ver.php?fid=174

I set "TBBROOT" variable to the directory in my bash_proflie and I unzipped the tar file and navigated to the bin folder and run tbbvars.sh file

I typed

```
sh tbbvars.sh intel64
```

I was trying to run examples but it complains as shown bleow

```
count_strings.cpp:38:37: fatal error: tbb/concurrent_hash_map.h: No such file or directory
```

I tried to set up the library path manually and I typed

```
g++ file.cpp -o output -L/path/to/the/lib/-ltbb
```

but it still complains.

How do I compile the sample code on Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is with #include paths (`-I`), not library paths (`-l`).

Comment: what do you mean by #include paths?

Comment: I typed g++ file.cpp -o test -I/path/to/the/lib/-ltbb and it still complains

Comment: You need to understand the difference between include paths (for headers) and library paths (for libraries) - your command line should be something like: `g++ file.cpp -o test -I /path/to/includes -L /path/to/libs -ltbb`

Comment: May be the tutorial by intel on TBB on ubuntu might help.
http://goparallel.sourceforge.net/compiling-tbb-programs-and-examples-on-linux-ubuntu/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I installed it from the Ubuntu repository, and it works without *any* problems.